# Take margin of an element in drag function javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have developed this function in javascript.As you can see i have set two variables counterLeft and counterUp to zero because i have set margin's properties of div1 to 0.I want that counterUp and counterLeft are the initial margin top and margin left of the div1.How can i take in automatic way initial margin property of the element?Is this a good way to implement drag and drop function?

```
 <div id="div1">

</div>


#div1{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background:green;
  margin-left:0px;



var oldx=0;
var positionx=0;
var oldy=0;
var positiony=0;
var counter=0;
var counterLeft=0;
var counterUp=0;
document.getElementById("div1").onmousedown=function(){

                     smetti=true;
                     oldx=event.clientX;
                     oldy=event.clientY;

                 };
          document.getElementById("div1").onmouseup=function(){

var oldx=0;
var positionx=0;
var oldy=0;
var positiony=0;
var counter=0;
var counterLeft=0;
var counterUp=0;
smetti=false;

                 };


var smetti=false;

window.onmousemove= function(){
if(smetti===true){

positionx=event.clientX;
positiony=event.clientY;
var differenceleft=positionx-oldx;
var differenceright=positionx - oldx;
var differenceup=positiony-oldy;
var differencedown=positiony - oldy;

if(counter>1){
 if(positionx<oldx){

    document.getElementById("div1").style.marginLeft =       counterLeft + differenceright +"px";
    counterLeft=counterLeft+differenceright;

              };

if(positionx>oldx){

    document.getElementById("div1").style.marginLeft =       counterLeft + differenceright +"px";
    counterLeft=counterLeft+differenceright;

              };

if(positiony<oldy){

    document.getElementById("div1").style.marginTop =         counterUp + differenceup +"px";
    counterUp=counterUp+differenceup;

              };

if(positiony>oldy){



    document.getElementById("div1").style.marginTop =         counterUp + differenceup +"px";
    counterUp=counterUp+differenceup;

              };
};

oldx=positionx;   
oldy=positiony;
counter=counter+1;
};


         };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cp9nya6g/1/

Comment: Step 1. Reduce code down to minimal amount to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I haven't understood excuse me:).My issue is how to take margin top and left of an element at the beginning of the function without set it manually.I don't know how to do that and I am afraid that my approach to this function is bad